# Parser for recursive expressions hangs in ghci

Tags: regex, parsing, haskell

I am trying to make a parser for the following recursive datatype:

```
data Expr = Val Int
          | Var Char
          | App Op Expr Expr
  deriving Show

data Op = Add | Sub | Mul | Div
  deriving Show
```

It should, for example, parse `"(1 + (a / -2))"` as `App Add (Val 1) (App Div (Var 'a') (Val (-2)))`. I've managed to write parsers for the `Val` and `Var` constructors as well as for `Op`'s constructors like so:

```
import Text.Regex.Applicative
import Data.Char

rNonnegativeIntegral :: (Read a, Integral a) => RE Char a
rNonnegativeIntegral = read <$> some (psym isDigit)

rNegativeIntegral :: (Read a, Integral a) => RE Char a
rNegativeIntegral = negate <$> (sym '-' *> rNonnegativeIntegral)

rIntegral :: (Read a, Integral a) => RE Char a
rIntegral = rNonnegativeIntegral <|> rNegativeIntegral

rVal :: RE Char Expr
rVal = Val <$> rIntegral

rVar :: RE Char Expr
rVar = Var <$> psym isAlpha

rOp = aux <$> (foldr1 (<|>) $ map sym "+-*/")
  where
    aux '+' = Add
    aux '-' = Sub
    aux '*' = Mul
    aux '/' = Div
```

When this is loaded into ghci it can produce the following output:

```
ghci> findLongestPrefix rVal "-271"
Just (Val (-271), "")
ghci> findLongestPrefix rVar "a"
Just (Var 'a', "")
ghci> findLongestPrefix rOp "-"
Just (Sub, "")
```

The trouble comes when I introduce this recursive definition for the `App` constructor:

```
whiteSpace :: RE Char String
whiteSpace = many $ psym isSpace

strictWhiteSpace :: RE Char String
strictWhiteSpace = some $ psym isSpace

rApp :: RE Char Expr
-- flip App :: Expr -> Op -> Expr
-- strictWhiteSpace after rOp to avoid conflict with rNegativeInteger
rApp = flip App <$> (sym '(' *> whiteSpace *> rExpr)
               <*> (whiteSpace *> rOp <* strictWhiteSpace)
               <*> (rExpr <* whiteSpace <* sym ')')

rExpr :: RE Char Expr
rExpr = rVal <|> rVar <|> rApp
```

This loads into ghci just fine, and all previous constructors still work. But `findLongestPrefix rApp "(1 + a)"` and many similar expressions cause ghci to hang and produce no output.

Through experimentation I've found that the issue happens in general when `rExpr` is passed in as the first argument to `<*`. For example, `findLongestPrefix (rExpr <* whiteSpace) "a)"` also causes ghci to hang.

Also, when the definition for `rExpr` is replaced by

```
rExpr = rVal <|> rVar
```

all of these hanging issues go away. Simple expressions like `"(1 + a)"` are able to be parsed, but support for recursive expressions is not available.

How can I implement a recursive parser here without hanging issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The language of expressions that you describe isn't regular. So you'll have to use a different library.

Luckily, essentially the same parser structure should work fine with most other parser combinator libraries. It should be as simple as substituting your new library's name for a few basic parsers in place of their regex-applicative analogs.

Comment: Interesting. Is there some kind of hierarchy of regex-like things, ordered in the sense that one can parse more structures than another?

Comment: @don01234 Yes... it's even traditionally named with exactly the word "[hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)". ^_^